# Why I am not getting actuall location after given by co-ordinates correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, location

```
import reverse_geocoder as rc 

import pprint

def locator():

    lat = float(input("\nEnter your lattitude co-ordinates: "))
    lon = float(input("Enter your longitude co-ordinates: "))

    locations = (lat, lon)
    location = rc.search(locations)
    print("\n")
    pprint.pprint(location)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    locator()
```

Comment: Input? Desired output?

Comment: While I am entering my two co-ordinates, It's giving me a location near by me. Not so near actually (minimum 100 km away location from the correct co-ordinates of the given location). I wanted to get the location actually I am looking for.

Comment: Enter your lattitude co-ordinates: 23.506657

Enter your longitude co-ordinates: 90.3443647

Loading formatted geocoded file...


[OrderedDict([('lat', '23.61352'),
              ('lon', '90.50298'),
              ('name', 'Narayanganj'),
              ('admin1', 'Dhaka'),
              ('admin2', ''),
              ('cc', 'BD')])]

Comment: Update your question with these details.

Answer (score 0):

Lat,Lon coordinates have a precision scale. You need to have at least 4-5 digits after the comma to get a meter/feet exact location. I am guessing from your question that it is likely due to a rounded number.

For example (Munich Train station):

```
48.139382, 11.559296
```

Changing the first number after the digit will move me a few km down the road.

If this doesn't provide an answer, could you please provide a coordinate example that you are using?